# python3-pip installed but pip3 command not found?

Tags: pip, ubuntu

I am testing a Python3 program in several computers. To do that, I need to install a library of Python with pip3.

So first, I was installing python3-pip in each computer (everyone is running a Kubuntu OS). Everything was OK, and then I installed the package I needed with pip3, and I managed to do that except for one computer.

In that computer, python3-pip was apparently installed succesfully, but when I look for the package, I get this error (the translation is homemade):

```
Command «pip3» was not found, may be you wanted to say:
 The command «pip» from the package «python-pip» (universe)
pip3: command not found
```

Comment: I have tried `pip-3.2` instead of `pip3` and it worked

Answer (score 1):

By the way, I had asked this question here https://superuser.com/questions/769920/python3-pip-installed-but-pip3-command-not-found too. There is an answer which has several votes, in my case, may be I was doing something wrong but it not worked. But try it, may be you are luckier than me!