# python3 and pip is installed on mac but pip3 command not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I know there are many similar questions, but none of the answers worked for me.

**Problem:** I have Python3 installed on my Mac (with anaconda), but when I tried to install a package using pip3, I received an error saying `pip3 command not found`. It seems no pip3 and also no python3-pip installed.

**Some info:**

```
(base) MacBook-Pro-8:~ mona$ python --version
Python 3.7.4
(base) MacBook-Pro-8:~ mona$ which python
/Users/mona/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
(base) MacBook-Pro-8:~ mona$ pip --version
pip 19.2.3 from /Users/mona/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
(base) MacBook-Pro-8:~ mona$ which pip
/Users/mona/opt/anaconda3/bin/pip
(base) MacBook-Pro-8:~ mona$ pip3 --version
-bash: pip3: command not found
(base) MacBook-Pro-8:~ mona$ locate pip3
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/python/py-pip/files/pip33
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/python/py-pip/files/pip34
/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/python/py-pip/files/pip35
```

Also, I see a different version of python3 when I use `brew info python3`:

[image]

Below are some of the similar questions I've already read:

- [pip3: command not found but python3-pip is already installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993086/pip3-command-not-found-but-python3-pip-is-already-installed)
- [python3-pip installed but pip3 command not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263191/python3-pip-installed-but-pip3-command-not-found)
- https://superuser.com/questions/769920/python3-pip-installed-but-pip3-command-not-found

Please help me. I'm really confused.

Thanks,

Comment: The `pip` installed in the virtual environment *is* the version you need; it's just named `pip` instead of `pip3` because it doesn't need to distinguish itself from some other Python-2-based `pip` installed elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip` and `pip3` are just two different names for the same program. Essentially, the only difference is the paths they are hard-coded to install into; `pip` is typically a version that installs to a Python 2 installation, and `pip3` to a Python 3 installation.

Inside your virtual environment, though, there typically is only *one* Python installation available; the purpose of the virtual environment is to provide "the" installation to use. As such, it simply uses names like `pip` and `python` for the commands rather than providing any kind of version-specific names. The names refer to whatever specific version was used to create the virtual environment.

Comment: just to make sure I understood you correctly, do you mean pip (in my case) is the same as pip3?